# Calling window.location.href in PhoneGap triggers web browser

Tags: javascript, ipad, browser, cordova, window.location

Hello
I'm trying to develop an application for iPad using PhoneGap. I would like to dinamically load  inside the index.html page the main page of an external website. 
Unfortunately using

```
window.location.href = "http://mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/index.py"
```

triggers the opening of a Safari window instead of using the PhoneGap container.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Claus

Comment: This other question has the right answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911255/phonegap-for-iphone-problem-loading-external-url

Comment: The answer can be found over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911255/phonegap-for-iphone-problem-loading-external-url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the AppDelegate.m file in the 'Classes' part of the project, and find webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType 
Make the function look like this and try again!

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];    
        return NO;
    }
    else {
       return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a simpler option: modify config.xml

> Open all links in WebView
>
> stay-in-webview with values true or false
>
> - example: `<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />`
> - if set to true, all links (even with target set to blank) will open in the app's webview
> - only use this preference if you want pages from your server to take over your entire app
> - default is false

Source: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml