# open link inside the phonegap program

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi guys I'm making a phonegap + jquery mobile program, the problem is that I've got a listview in the phonegap that is being loaded by an external site, in the leaf of the list have an a href to a site with the html that i want to be opened in the program. When I click in the leaf it opens the link in the mobile browser instead of the phonegap program, and I would like to make it open the links inside the program instead of the mobile browser.

I've already tried rel=external  and data-ajax="false" but everything is failing and opening in the mobile browser, can some one help me please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911255/phonegap-for-iphone-problem-loading-external-url/7779187#7779187

Answer (score 0):

you could maybe try putting an iframe and open the link in that?

Comment: no , I cant use Iframe , i need to change the content of the phonegap program to the page that it links , im using in some parts the load() function of jquery but i dont know how to use it inside an jquery mobile listview.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'd do it in Android:

[PhoneGap for iPhone: problem loading external URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911255/phonegap-for-iphone-problem-loading-external-url/7768575#7768575)

A similar mechanism exists for iOS. You can specify external URLs that should not be launched in an external browser in *PhoneGap.plist*

Answer (score 0):

Use the `childbrowser` plugin for Phonegap. That will open the link inside the app only.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to accomplish a similar thing by making IFrames embed in the app (instead of opening in a browser )and this fixed the issue for me .
 In Xcode, modify the AppDelegate.m file,
replace the shouldStartLoadWithRequest section
with this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return [ self.viewController webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
    }
}
```

this is for Cordova 1.5.x,, on iOS obviously