# Phonegap Android App, open links within app?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is it possible to open a url within a PhoneGap compiled HTML5 app?

We need to process our orders by sending a url to an external https webpage. We would like to open this page within our app rather than externally in the phone's browser?

I know that Phonegap uses the webview class, but have no idea how to alter it to make URLs open internally!

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Without childbrowser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911255/phonegap-for-iphone-problem-loading-external-url/7779187#7779187

Answer (score 4, accepted):

checkout the phonegap plugin childbrowser: https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser  It enables you to open a second browser window with the other url.