# How to Open Google Play store from Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, google-play, itunes

I want to open google play store from my phonegap application to install another notification app. How will be able to do that? I guess ios its easy by URL navigation scheme. But google does not support all url navigation schemes. I checked only twitter was working with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open an URL to this app and when the user click on download it will redirect it play store application.

Look at this one [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755275/phonegap-android-app-open-links-within-app)

or you can use one of this:

```
window.location.href("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

or

```
window.open("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

or u just launch it in direct way look at this example and document:
[Document](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

[Example](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki)