# Open Play Store with PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I'm developing a very simple webapp with Phonegapp, and I want to open the Play Store APP (Android), when the user clicks on a specific button. I read some q%a but I don't know how I can do it
I have a index.html like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Just a development test ->dany_danay</title>

    <link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var watchID = null;
    var pictureSource;   // Origen de la imagen
    var destinationType; // Formato del valor retornado

    // Espera a que PhoneGap conecte con el dispositivo.
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    function alertDismissed() {
        // do something
    }




    </script>
  </head>
  <body>


<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Your SmartPhone info</h1>
    </div>



    <center><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tusmartphone.dany&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS50dXNtYXJ0cGhvbmUuZGFueSJd" rel="external" /><img src="http://media.go2speed.org/brand/files/offermobi/1981/20130605194659-WARFAL_b01_320X50_04.png"/></a>


    </center>


  </body>
</html>
```

I tried adding rel="external" or rel="system" in the 
and this js function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  updateAndroidMarketLinks();
  // some more core here ... 

  function updateAndroidMarketLinks()
  {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if (0 <= ua.indexOf("android")) {
      // we have android
      $("a[href^='http://play.google.com/']").each(function() {
        this.href = this.href.replace(/^http:\/\/play\.google\.com\//,
          "market://");
      });
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

I have to call a intent, but not sure how i can do this with html or js...
Dont know how to prove this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325864/phonegap-android-open-play-store or this: [How to Open Google Play store from Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308107/how-to-open-google-play-store-from-phonegap) http://tannerburson.com/blog/2012/05/28/IntentChooser-my-first-PhoneGap-Cordova-plugin/

Answer (score 4):

You want to use market links.

```
market://details?id=<package_name>
```

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html

Comment: The link is broken