# a href tag opens google play store link in browser rather than the default play store app?

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am building a mobile App using HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript with PhoneGap API. I have 2 versions of my app one free and one paid. All i want to do is if the user wants to buy the paid version he should be redirected to the Play Store so i am using the following code just an example.

```
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.disney.toystorysmashitfree_goo" >Remove Adds</a>
```

However this code does open play store but in a browser not the default google play store app. How do i get this feature working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this should help.
This is the documentation on how you should link to your app in google play-store.

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html

Otherwise, someone else on stack has already had the same problem, maybe his question will be of some help.

[How to Open Google Play store from Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308107/how-to-open-google-play-store-from-phonegap?rq=1)

Comment: the doc link helped. <a href="market://details?id=com.disney.toystorysmashitfree_goo" >Remove Adds</a> thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use Phonegap In app browser

```
window.open('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.disney.toystorysmashitfree_goo', '_system');
```

and before that you must add plugin

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

Comment: i am using phonegap build to build my project in this case how do i add the plugin ? Is it that i need to add in index.html file ? any tutorial link would be of great help