# How can I load a webpage inside the phonegap webview?

Tags: android, cordova

I want to be able to link to a webpage inside the phonegap webview that loads an external webpage inside the same phonegap webview. If I do this, it loads inside the webview:

```
public class App extends DroidGap {
   @Override
   public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      super.loadUrl("http://google.com");
   }
}
```

However, I want to have an internal page launched first, with a link to the external page, so I do this:

```
public class App extends DroidGap {
   @Override
   public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
   }
}
```

and I have a link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="navigator.app.loadUrl('http://google.com')">Google</a>
```

but this link launches google outside the app, in the web browser, instead of in the phonegap webview. What can I do to make sure the link to the external page is launched inside the app's phonegap webview?

Comment: Where do I add this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ahhh.. Found the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911255/phonegap-for-iphone-problem-loading-external-url/7768575#7768575). 
I had to add

```
<access origin="www.google.com"/>
```

to the `phonegap.xml` file.

Answer (score 10):

This seems to have changed, and access origin seems to have no effect. If you're using the cordova whitelist plugin, as seems to be standard. You need to use allow-navigation in your config.xml file. Without this it will open your web browser.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
<allow-navigation href="https://google.com/*" />
```

Then you can use window.location = 'https://google.com' to move to another webpage within your JS.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Saved me a lot of grief. The other answers are outdated for v4. I just added <access origin="*" />

Comment: I do not think that the <plugin> tag is necessary.  Just the <allow-navigation>.

Comment: I tried and it did not seem to work for me with CLI 5.1.1. On Android it always open in a new tab :( even with `<allow-navigation href="*" />` and the plugin installed

Comment: @SebastienLorber did you found any alternative? i am struggling with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

In the latest phonegab (1.7) in Cordova.plist there is a Key: OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView set this to YES.

Comment: ..sorry, this is obviously only for iOS.