# OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView for Android in Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on application which will handle a few device-specific things, but then redirect the user to an online webpage. This is all working well in iOS build and I am trying to get it to work in Android.

Currently in Android, the app loads, but does nothing with if I have a `window.location.href = ...` call in the `window.onload`. One of the settings that was necessary for iOS was `OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView`. Is there a similar setting for Android? How do you set it? Any other recommendations?

Comment: U made it working on iphone right?... How did u contact the server in Iphone?

Comment: The page itself essentially does a `window.location.href = 'url'`. In xcode I updated the whitelisted hosts and changed the `OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView` setting to true. The one other thing I'm realizing I changed is I currently return `YES` in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType` (I am going to change it shortly to only return `YES` for the domain in question). Is there something similiar on the android side?

Comment: Please read this article.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596772/how-can-i-load-a-webpage-inside-the-phonegap-webview

Comment: Please read following article:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596772/how-can-i-load-a-webpage-inside-the-phonegap-webview

Comment: Please read following article:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596772/how-can-i-load-a-webpage-inside-the-phonegap-webview

Comment: Please read following article:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596772/how-can-i-load-a-webpage-inside-the-phonegap-webview

Answer (score 0):

According to me... The Concept of using Phonegap will be creating a universal code which will work for every mobile platform...

if you need to make a server request then do it like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Index Page</title>

<!-- Adding viewport -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Adding Phonegap scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
src="cordova/cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>

<!-- Adding jQuery mobile and jQuery scripts & CSS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript"
src="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {

$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    cache : false,
    url : "http://192.168.1.198:9051/something.xml"
            + "?time=" + Date.now(),
    data : {
        key : "value"
    },
    dataType : "xml",
    success : function(xml) {
        console.log("Success Page1");
    },
    error : function(xhr) {

    }
});
}
</script>
```

In case of **iOS**... The above code will not contact the Server because apple doesnt allow us to contact to external servers until we specify it like through `ExternalHosts` in cordova.plist

But in case of **Android**. You don not have to do anything.It will contact the server with out any external configurations..:)

Comment: I think in a round about way this "answers" my questions. I am able to load an external URL using the super.loadUrl in the Java code. Unfortunately not the server I'm after (that timesout), but that's probably a whole other ball of wax...

Answer (score 0):

```
<access origin="www.google.com"/>
```

to the res/xml/config.xml file.