# Upload files to Dropbox folder with cordova app

Tags: cordova, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am working on a cordova app which require users to upload files to a Dropbox folder of some predefined account How can I use dropbox JS SDK to upload files, is it possible? Is there any cordova plugin which I can use to achieve this functionality.

Comment: This is a good tutorial on how to achieve this:
http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/149/how-to-use-dropbox-in-a-cordova-application

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I made a PhoneGap plugin for Android that uses the Dropbox Sync API. [The source code is here on GitHub](https://github.com/rossmartin/phonegap-dropbox-sync). [I made a blog post on setup here](http://rossmartindev.blogspot.com/2013/08/phonegap-plugin-for-dropbox-sync-api.html).</strike> The sync API has been deprecated.

I also made a PhoneGap plugin for iOS that uses the Dropbox SDK.  [I made a blog post on setup and use here](http://rossmartindev.blogspot.com/2012/11/using-dropbox-sdk-with-phonegap-aka.html).

[You should check out this post here if you wish to use the Dropbox JS SDK with PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041810/dropbox-js-authentication-in-cordova-phonegap/18046968#comment27035135_18046968).

Comment: The Dropbox Sync and Datastore APIs are now deprecated: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/04/deprecating-the-sync-and-datastore-apis/

Answer (score 0):

For how to use the JS SDK, below is taken from the [DropBox Tech Blog](https://tech.dropbox.com/2012/08/some-love-for-javascript-applications-2/):

"...[register for a Dropbox API key](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps), [set up an application in your Dropbox](https://dl-web.dropbox.com/spa/pjlfdak1tmznswp/powered_by.js/public/index.html), borrow [sample code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cf8h6d6bu2k9ugy/sP0aruaBww), and read the [library documentation](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/master/doc/getting_started.md)".

As for the plugin, I am not aware of one.