# jquery mobile + phonegap = base URL file://

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using links with relative paths within my phonegap application.  I've been testing on both iOS and Android.

On android links such as '/about' will attempt to load from 'file:///about' rather than the correct relative URL.

On initial load, $('base').attr('href') returns the full and proper domain of the website.

I can't tell if this is changing, or why, for the app crashes upon error.

This has happened before!  Although I normally have not experienced this issue with iOS, it did appear once.  After using the camera to capture a photo, the base path is changed by some internal combination of phonegap and jqm, and must be changed back.

Is this a phonegap issue?  Or something from jquery mobile?

Thanks!  This is being quite an elusive bug.

Comment: do you solved this problem ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding a data-url attribute to the pages seemed to do the trick

Comment: could you elaborate?  data-url=? and where? html, head, meta ?

Comment: I had it set on every page to the page's web path.  But I think that was a false positive.  Here's the real issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899608/what-is-the-state-of-whitelisting-in-phonegap-1-3-0/8899637#8899637 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911255/phonegap-for-iphone-problem-loading-external-url

Answer (score 0):

in your example you mentioned /about not working on android, but this is not a relative url "about" without the slash is one.

so /about leading to file:///about is correct behaviour. Can you try a real relative url instead?

Comment: Just ran a test.  I set the data-url attribute to the full path, including protocol and domain, and tested two buttons, one to /send_feedback and one to simply send_feedback.  The error has now changed, and is the same in both cases: "./sendfeedback was not found"