# PhoneGap: Can't Load External Website

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cordova, external-links

I'm trying to display a page, for example, www.google.com, in a PhoneGap application.  However, I can't get the page to open in Safari, much less within PhoneGap (which is my ultimate goal).

I saw this post: [PhoneGap for iPhone: problem loading external URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911255/phonegap-for-iphone-problem-loading-external-url), and have tried from it the following:

-As described in the solution to that question, I have modified my **AppDelegate.m** file.

-After doing this, in part of the **index.html** file (created by PhoneGap), I have this code:

```
window.location("http://google.com");
```

Although the project compiles and builds fine, I see only a blank page.

I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.location("http://google.com");
```

isn't valid JavaScript. You need:

```
window.location.replace("http://google.com");
```

or

```
window.location.href="http://google.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .href and check this post for more information about PhoneGap and external URL: [PhoneGap for iPhone: problem loading external URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911255/phonegap-for-iphone-problem-loading-external-url)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this charmer in your MainViewController.m It works for me in cordova 1.7.0 cordova 1.9.0 and cordova 2.1.0

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request   navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
NSURL *url = [request URL];

// Intercept the external http requests and forward to Safari.app
// Otherwise forward to the PhoneGap WebView
if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
return NO;
}
else {
return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
}
    }
```