# Change the page programmatically in phonegap

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova

I am trying to change the current HTML page programmatically in PhoneGap (iPhone). Currently I am using `window.location.href` but it's not doing its job. What is an alternate solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dynamically change your url when using [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) you really should (perhaps even must) use [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/); for example -

```
$.mobile.changePage('index.html', { 
  dataUrl : "index.html?page=events", data : { 
    'page' : 'events' 
  }, reloadPage : false, changeHash : true 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use ajax to change html page.
If you are using phoneGap api then if you move from one page to other then i will take more time to load phoneGap api. All javascript functions load again so what i prefer that you need to use ajax to load different HTML page.

You need to use JQuery MObile with PhoneGap. JQuery Mobile Load each html page using ajax

[Read this for more information](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html)

[PhoneGap and JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html)

Comment: There should be a way to do it in simple java script (without using jquery).

Comment: Yes you can load entire page using JQuery load() function. In JavaScript See this example  http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Comment: But what if someone doesn't want to use jquery. For example it doesn't make sense to include jquery just to navigate to a different page. Can't it be done using simple JS?

Comment: I got the answer but cause of less reputation i cant answer my question unless 8 hrs. The solution is just have to alter a function in AppDelegate.m file. This is the thread answering my prob:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911255/phonegap-for-iphone-problem-loading-external-url