# Phonegap 1.7.0 workaround for opening Webview URL´s

Tags: cordova, webview, cross-platform, mobile-website

I have a problem with the phonegap version 1.7.0rc1 and the development under iOS 5.
I´m using XCode 4.3 and the cordova plugin for a cross-platform web application.

Everybody aims the same goal, one application which runs on any target-platform. Phonegap could be a solution. But I´m tired of building every app from new and release it in every store (Play and AppStore) everytime I fix or change something in the www content.

I would like to have a remote www folder also using the phonegap container instead of copying or clone my www folder into every project. Is there a way with version 1.7.0 to load external URL´s without opening a Safari Browser window?

I was taking a look into this post [PhoneGap for iPhone: problem loading external URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911255/phonegap-for-iphone-problem-loading-external-url) but it seems to be working only with version 1.4.0

Or is there a another way for releasing an app once and make changes to the content unindependent? I´m using native functions like the camera but also want to have a web application and thats why I´m asking for a phonegap "workaround".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cordova.plist set the key `OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView` to `YES` and make sure you have whitelisted your hostname in `ExternalHosts` of the same plist