# Prevent iframe opening new window

Tags: html, cordova, iframe, sencha-touch-2

In my Sencha-Touch-2 and Phonegap App I want to use an iFrame for displaying HTML content, but
I have problem.

iFrame opens in a new window if the src URL is relative.

```
Ext.define('test.view.HTMLPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'mainhtmlpanel',

config: {
    id: 'mainHTMLPanel',
    scrollable: 'vertical',
    html: '<iframe name="myIframe" width="' + (screen.width - 350) + '" src="file:///mnt/sdcard/MyApp/MyFolder/MyFolder2/32674059.html"></iframe>'
}
});
```

How could I prevent iFrame opening the `32674059.html` in a new window ?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From
[PhoneGap for iPhone: problem loading external URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911255/phonegap-for-iphone-problem-loading-external-url)

In Phonegap 1.7, in Cordova.plist there is a Key: OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView. Set this to YES.