# window.location.href not working in phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova

I want to redirect to another page in Phonegap.

I have written the following code in javascript but it is not getting redirected:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

Can anyone advise why it is not working?

Comment: use only window.location ="http://www.google.com" may it work

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911255/phonegap-for-iphone-problem-loading-external-url.

Comment: check with document.window.location

Comment: did you add exception to your whitelist?

Comment: Yes i made OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView = YES in cordova .plist but also window.location is not working.

Comment: Wait I'll have a try in my env. I'll let you know if I made it work :)

Comment: Oh no! I think I get your problem! Do you get a blank screen???

Comment: i have called it in a function inside if statement function login(){
            
            var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
            var y=document.forms["myForm"]["pwd"].value; if(x=="Shraddha" && y=="shraddha")
            {
                //alert("hi");
            window.location = "http://www.google.com";}}

Comment: no i am on the same screen. i do not get blank screen.

Comment: Did you made any other modification in your cordova.plist file, other than "OpenWhitelistURLsInWebView = YES" ?

Comment: no i did not make any modification

Comment: ok please wait, I'll post a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to allow navigation of external sites inside your application by configuring the whitelist.

You have to use `allow-navigation` tag like this:

`<allow-navigation href="http://www.google.com/*" />`

Comment: This is part of cordova-plugin-whitelist which has to be added before also.

Comment: Whitelist plugin is android only, the question was about iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

- Open your file `Cordova.plist` file
- Right click on `ExternalHosts` -> `Add Row`
- Set the `String` value of the new added row to `*`.

So, you should have your new added row like this:

```
Item0            String          *
```

Normally, you should replace `*` with the external URL that you want to provide access to (like `http://www.google.com` for instance), but I used `*` to make sure that the problem comes from there or not.

For more information, check the "Domain Whitelist Guide" section of the online doc: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide .

---

Here's a simple working example using `window.location.href`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>               
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            function init() {
                window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
            }      
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="init();">
    </body>                

</html>
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: :( ... Did you get any error on console? Also, is the `alert("hi");` triggered if not commented ?

Comment: Do you get any error on console? I'll post a simple example using window.location.href... Then, you could try it to see if the problem comes from there ok? Please wait...

Comment: Please have a try with the example I've just posted :). I hope this will work for you :S

Comment: yes your example worked for me. But it does not work in my application.

Comment: You may have an code issue somewhere :S. What you can do is to open your js file with your browser (ex: firefox) and check if you don't have any synthax error by using your console (or Firebug :) ).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's the page you are moving to.  Does that page have the phongap.js files in it etc?

Try a simple test: create a new HTML page with just the basic elements and a couple words in the body so you know you are there. Save it as test.html. Now try window.location="test.html".

If that works then you know it's something in the new page.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your framework initializations? Make sure jquery and phonegap are completely loaded before you try to change the page. Or else phonegap will hang and break.

Take a look here: [Correct way of using JQuery-Mobile/Phonegap together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945643/correct-way-of-using-jquery-mobile-phonegap-together)

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me with Cordova 4. Can you try remote debugging with Google Chrome and see what happen in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

Try without `href`:

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use like `window.location` or `window.location.href` and it stll doesn't work in IOS or safrai.

you can use this:

```
var isAndroid = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/android/ig);
        var targetUrl = 'your url';
        window.location = targetUrl;

if(!isAndroid) {
    var doc = window.document,
        ifr = doc.createElement('iframe');
    ifr.src = targetUrl;
    ifr.style.cssText = 'display:none;';
    doc.body.appendChild(ifr);
}
```